# How to transform multiple dummy variables to string

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dummy-variable

So I have data set like this:

```
    a_1 a_2 a_3
0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   1   1
3   1   0   0
```

And I want to cut in to one column so it looks like it:

```
    a
0   1|2
1   2  
2   2|3
3   1
```

This way I can then easily redo it back to dummy if I need it later.

So how to do it? pandas.from_dummies - works only for one choice cases so maybe there is a fast way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting row data to list such `[1 ,1 ,0]` and find out the index number with `1`, so output will be `[0, 1]` as you start index from `1`, I have incremented the list elemnts with `+1`. last converted list to string using join fun with `|` character.

Code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join([str(i+1) for i, e in enumerate(list(x)) if e == 1]),axis=1)
```

Ouput:

```
0    1|2
1      2
2    2|3
3      1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

One option if you have a single level (a):

```
(df.mask(df.eq(0))
   .stack()
   .reset_index(-1)['level_1']
   .str.extract('_(\w+)', expand=False)
   .groupby(level=0).agg('|'.join)
)
```

Quick hack alternative:

```
df.dot('|'+df.columns.str.extract('_(\w+)', expand=False)).str[1:]
```

output:

```
0    1|2
1      2
2    2|3
3      1
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

For more levels:

```
(df
 .mask(df.eq(0))
 .set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)
 .stack([0, 1])
 .reset_index(-1)['level_2']
 .groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg('|'.join)
 .unstack()
)
```

output:

```
     a
0  1|2
1    2
2  2|3
3    1
```